# Window resizing causes the image to move to the left

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site, where it contains two divs (one header and one below). Now, when I resize the window the image in the header moves to the left side .
Below is the HTML of the code :

```
<div id="header"><img src="images/test" style="position:absolute;right:170px;top: 25px"/>
```

CSS :

```
div#header {

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50px;  
    border: 2px solid black;
}

div#container {
float:left;
background:url('./css/bg.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;background-attachment:contain;background-size: local;
position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 695px; 
    border: 2px solid black;

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chju4/1/)
How can I adjust such that the image in the header remains where it was before (to the right end) when the window is resized and not move to the left

Comment: I'm not understanding what the problem is... the JSFiddle works fine. The picture doesn't move when the window is re-sized.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Looks 100% fine to me on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari...

Comment: FireFox again, huhm, too annoying...

Comment: may be i should upgrade browser

Comment: Do you mean that as you resize, the image gets pushed left little by little until it is no longer on the right side at all, and eventually gets pushed off the left side of screen all together when you resize small enough? Is this the problem you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** If percentages are an option try the below.

Use percentages, that will ensure it sticks to a certain location: http://jsfiddle.net/chju4/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="header"><img src="images/test" style="position:absolute;right:30%;top: 25px"/>
</div>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#header {

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50px;  
    border: 2px solid black;
}

div#container {
float:left;
background:url('./css/bg.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;background-attachment:contain;background-size: local;
position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 695px; 
    border: 2px solid black;

}
```

Comment: Yup, you stole the words right out of my mouth... just beat me by about 12 minutes :) Pretty sure this solves it +1

Comment: @MarkM Haha I wasn't sure if percentages are an option so I said f'it here yu go anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I could be misunderstanding your issue, but I think it has to do with `right:170px;` in the image's inline style. The black box is relative - it shrinks with the window, but the image is always 170px from the right side - so when the window is, say, only 100px wide, the image is push off screen. Try changing `right:170px` to a percentage or em.